# How to use OnClickListner on CardView in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I try to do something like this : 
[image]

My problem and when I click on my `ImageView`, my `CardView` is expanded, but the n-th `CardView` is also expanded which takes the expanded `CardView` on which I clicked. I do not understand why my `onClick` method is also applied to the other `CardView`.

**My Adapter**

```
public class CardsViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardsViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Game[] mDataset;
    int rotationAngle = 0;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public LinearLayout test2;
        public TextView test3;
        boolean isPopupVisible;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_cards);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_description_game_more);
            test2 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.popup_layout);
            test3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_view);
            isPopupVisible = false;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public CardsViewAdapter(Game[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public CardsViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cards_resume_game, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        //...

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        //TODO : complete
        final int pos = position;
        holder.mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset[position].getId_game()));
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("POS","actual pos = "+pos);
                holder.test3.setText("Position : "+pos);
                // Perform action on click
                if (holder.isPopupVisible) {
                    holder.isPopupVisible = false;

                    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation",rotationAngle, rotationAngle + 180);
                    anim.setDuration(500);
                    anim.start();
                    rotationAngle += 180;
                    rotationAngle = rotationAngle%360;

                    CardsAnimationHelper.collapse(holder.test2);

                } else {
                    holder.isPopupVisible = true;

                    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation",rotationAngle, rotationAngle + 180);
                    anim.setDuration(500);
                    anim.start();
                    rotationAngle += 180;
                    rotationAngle = rotationAngle%360;

                    CardsAnimationHelper.expand(holder.test2);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want some specific `CardView` of your list should be expanded? Or when a `CardView` is already expanded, you want to close it on clicking over another `CardView` to expand?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I want that some specific CardView of my list should be expanded

Comment: So from your comment I understood you need to expand some of your specific `CardView` to be expanded and the others as collapsed all the time. Right?

Comment: @ReazMurshed Right !

Comment: OK. I'm writing an answer few hours later. I'm crazy busy right now. Sorry.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Ok, thx

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already have your `Game` class. Just add a new attribute in that class named `expanded`.

```
public Class Game {
    public int id;
    public String description;

    // Add an extra attribute to track the checked status
    // By default, set the checked status to false
    public boolean expanded = false;
}
```

Now as you now have an attribute to track the expanded status, you can easily do something like this.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final int pos = position;
    holder.mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset[position].id));

    // Set the expanded or collapsed mode here
    if(mDataset[position].expanded) expandView(holder.test2);
    else collapseView(holder.test2);

    // Now set the onClickListener like this
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.test3.setText("Position : "+pos);

            // Animate the imageView here
            animateImageView(holder.imageView);

            // Toggle the expanded attribute value
            if(mDataset[position].expanded) mDataset[position].expanded = false;
            else mDataset[position].expanded = true;

            // Now call notifyDataSetChanged to make the change to effect
            refreshList();
        }
    });
}

// Extra functions inside your adapter class to improve readability
private void collapseView(View view) {
    CardsAnimationHelper.collapse(view);
}

private void expandView(View view) {
    CardsAnimationHelper.expand(view);
}

private void animateImageView(ImageView imageView) {
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "rotation",rotationAngle, rotationAngle + 180);
    anim.setDuration(animationDuration);
    anim.start();
    rotationAngle += 180;
    rotationAngle = rotationAngle % 360;
}

long animationDuration = 500;

private void refreshList() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, animationDuration);
}
```

Comment: ok it's working fine but before my animator was only on my imageview and not all the card, how i can keep my effect ?

Comment: yeah, Is that I did it myself but the imageView of all the cards turns

Comment: See the updated answer. Accept and upvote if helpful.

Comment: it's not working and i have a other problem, my setText, here : `holder.test3.setText("Position : "+pos);` is not modified in the view that is displayed. And when i expand or collapse a cardView the view is reset to the first element and goes down very quickly to the current element, there is way so that one does not see this?

Comment: The animation can't work because it launches it and that afterwards we ask to refresh the view.

Comment: Then add a delay between animation call and `notifyDataSetChanged` call by adding `handler.postDelayed`. See the updated answer.

Comment: It's good but I still have the "flash". I made a video to show you. It does not look very good for the 6th but the 7th is pretty obvious. I think this is because of `notifyDataSetChanged ();` which reloads the list from the beginning and scrolls to the current item. How can we not see him?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LMfg4tJlisVVlXajVuVlIyd3c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132483/discussion-between-reaz-murshed-and-filol).

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the n-th item in your list is re-using the view that you expanded. That is what the view holder is for, to reuse views and not create them everytime.

For you to fix that make sure check the expanded state of your view onBindViewHolder again and not only onClick.

Comment: Can you explain a little more your solution, I'm not sure to understand

Answer (score 0):

Add PopupVisible to your Game class as a variable, and in onBindViewHolder expanded the cardview only when game.getPopupVisible is true :

```
public class CardsViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardsViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Game[] mDataset;
    int rotationAngle = 0;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public LinearLayout test2;
        public TextView test3;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_cards);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_description_game_more);
            test2 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.popup_layout);
            test3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_view);

        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public CardsViewAdapter(Game[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public CardsViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cards_resume_game, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        //...

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        //TODO : complete
        final int pos = position;
        Game game=mDataset[position];
        holder.mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset[position].getId_game()));
        if (game.getPopupVisible()) {
                    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation",rotationAngle, rotationAngle + 180);
                    anim.setDuration(500);
                    anim.start();
                    rotationAngle += 180;
                    rotationAngle = rotationAngle%360;
                    CardsAnimationHelper.collapse(holder.test2);}
        else....
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("POS","actual pos = "+pos);
                holder.test3.setText("Position : "+pos);
                // Perform action on click
                if (game.getPopupVisible()) {
                    game.setPopupVisible(false);

                    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation",rotationAngle, rotationAngle + 180);
                    anim.setDuration(500);
                    anim.start();
                    rotationAngle += 180;
                    rotationAngle = rotationAngle%360;

                    CardsAnimationHelper.collapse(holder.test2);

                } else {
                   game.setPopupVisible(true);

                    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation",rotationAngle, rotationAngle + 180);
                    anim.setDuration(500);
                    anim.start();
                    rotationAngle += 180;
                    rotationAngle = rotationAngle%360;

                    CardsAnimationHelper.expand(holder.test2);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```